# fixed sidebar floating at page height

Tags: css, sidebar, fixed

In my work, I want the right-sidebar, left-sidebar, mid-sidebar boxes to be at page height and to stay fixed on the page by scrolling after the hedar. It should be placed between the footer and the header. like the twitch chat section

```css
body{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
.header-wrapper{width:100%;background:gray;}
.outer-wrapper{width:100%;height:auto;}
.left-sidebar{width:15%;background:red;height:1000px;float:left;}
.main-wrapper{width:45%;background:yellow;height:1000px;float:left;}
.mid-sidebar{width:20%;background:blue;height:1000px;float:left;}
.right-sidebar{width:20%;background:orange;height:1000px;float:left;}
.footer-wrapper{width:100%;background:green;}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="header-wrapper">HEADER
</div>

<div class="outer-wrapper">

<div class="left-sidebar">
</div>

<div class="main-wrapper">
</div>

<div class="mid-sidebar">
</div>

<div class="right-sidebar">
</div>



</div>

<div class="footer-wrapper">FOOTER
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: As far as I understand all you need is a sticky header. You have done the columns. Is that correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make the columns the way I want. I want it to be fixed page height and floating. like the twitch chat section

Comment: I have no idea what this chat is. Could you please upload a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Fixed and floating boxes at the height of the page located between the header and footer